# Как задать глобальный Z-Index в WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Есть канва. На ней расположено несколько однообразных сборных элементов типа `MyControl`. Эти элементы состоят из круга и вспомогательных линий.

Само собой, элемент, добавленный последним перекрывает элемент, добавленный раньше. Но мне нужно сделать так, чтобы вспомогательные линии верхнего элемента не перекрывали кружок нижнего элемента. Как это сделать?

Рисунок прилагаю. Как видите, линия, выходящая снизу (она относится к элементу, который выше по Z-индексу) перекрывает собой зеленый кружок. А мне нужно, чтобы кружки всех элементов были выше других элементов. Просто задать у них `Canvas.ZIndex` я не могу, так как элементы сборные и в своем составе имеют еще как минимум одну канву.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попахивает чем-то подобным костылю, вы бы описали чего хотите достичь этим. Быть может, есть иные пути решения вопроса?

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov, я в последнем абзаце написал, чего хочу достичь.